# A Character "y" is Displayed On All WordPress Pages

Tags: html, apache, bitnami

I have recently switched my hosting provider. I am not sure where the problem might have originated from but before html tag, letter "y" is displayed on all WordPress pages including the admin pages. It is now the first letter that my webpages serve.

A test html page created (not part of WordPress) doesn't show this! I am using Bitnami WordPress image on AWS.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You would get better answers if you provide an html sample from your WordPress. Make sure it does have the problem you refer to.

Comment: Can you provide a link so we can see what's going on?

Comment: @MichaelKolber http://idevji.com

Comment: @HessamShekhasnay `y`<!doctype html>
 <!--[if !IE]>
 <html class="no-js non-ie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 7 ]>
 <html class="no-js ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 8 ]>
 <html class="no-js ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 9 ]>
 <html class="no-js ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: Why is there a random "y" before <!doctype html> ?

Comment: @HessamShekhasnay That is what the question is!

Comment: Another good question is why is all of your `<head>` content in your `<body>` tag? Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: @MichaelKolber It's not so! Can you please recheck.

Comment: @DDC I see meta, script, style, and title tags all in `<body>`. The only thing in `<head>` is `<script src="https://idevji.com/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.9.8" type="text/javascript" defer=""></script>`.

Comment: The only hint I have is that when I use view-source in Chrome, the `y` doesn't appear. So maybe it's some rogue JavaScript that's causing it?

Comment: @MichaelKolber That is strange! At my end everything is in head tag!

Comment: @DDC Try using a different browser. Also try clearing your cache/cookies on your main browser, and maybe even clearing your DNS cache (as you mentioned you switched providers).

Comment: @MichaelKolber I can see it in Chrome too! Plus JS could not be doing this as it apperas even on the wp-admin side.

Comment: What do you mean it appears on the wp-admin side? If you open your `index.php` (or whatever your main page is based on), is the `y` there?

Comment: @MichaelKolber Yes it is everywhere except the page I created outside WP (http://idevji.com/hello.html)

Comment: I mean when you open the actual PHP code.

Comment: @MichaelKolber In WordPress I don't have individual PHP files

Comment: OK! I messed up with my wp-config.php file where a `y` was typed by error!